# perl + convert json to csv file

Tags: linux, perl, csv, json

the following perl script should convert json to csv

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $file = 'players.json';

open( my $input, "<", $file ) or die $!;

my $json_data = decode_json(
   do { local $/; <$input> }
);
 foreach my $player_id ( keys %{$json_data} ) {
 foreach my $fixture (
      @{ $json_data->{$player_id}->{fixture_history}->{all} } )
  {
       print join( ",",
          $player_id, $json_data->{$player_id}->{web_name},
           @{$fixture}, "\n", );
    }

   }
```

json file is under /tmp folder - players.json

```
ls /tmp | grep  players.json
players.json
```

when I run the script under /tmp I get:

```
./jsonTOcsv.pl

Not a HASH reference at ./uri.pl line 15, <$input> line 1.
```

please advice what is wrong here?

Comment: Basically you are expecting a hash of array of hash ... structure, but it seems it is not.

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is this:

> Not a HASH reference at ./uri.pl line 15, <$input> line 1.

Looks like the line it is complaining about is this:

```
foreach my $player_id ( keys %{$json_data} ) {
```

In this line, you assume that `$json_data` is a reference to a hash and you try to dereference it with `%{$json_data}`. But it seems that `$json_data` doesn't contain a reference to a hash. Perl hates it if you try to treat something that isn't a hash reference as if it was a hash reference, so it throws the error that you see and kills the program.

So you need to know what is in `$json_data` if it isn't a hash reference. There are a few ways to do that.

1. You could look at the contents of your `players.json` file. If the JSON data in that file is a hash, it will start with a `{` character.
2. You could print a dump of `$json_data` inside your program using something like [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper). Once again, a data structure that is a hash reference will start with a `{`.
3. You could use [`ref()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) to print what `$json_data` is a reference to - `print ref $json_data`.

In my experience, JSON data is either stored in a hash or an array. I suspect you'll find that one of two things is true.

1. `players.json` does not contain valid JSON, so your call to `decode_json()` is failing and `$json_data` is undefined.
2. `players.json` contains an array, rather than a hash.